# Bash script to re-run program when it finishes or crashes

Tags: bash, scripting

This is what I have so far:

```
until python MyApp.py; do
  echo "App crashed... restarting..." >&2
  sleep 1
done
```

This will re-run the program when it crashes, but not when the program finishes on its own.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: So it should always run and show an error message for failures? Maybe use exit codes in an `IF`-loop with an infinite `WHILE`-loop as a wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this would do the trick for you ?

```
while True;
do
 python MyApp.py || echo "App crashed... restarting..." >&2
 echo "Press Ctrl-C to quit." && sleep 1
done
```